# Sleep in a while loop gets its own pid

Tags: linux, bash, process-control

I have a bash script that does some parallel processing in a loop.  I don't want the parallel process to spike the CPU, so I use a sleep command.  Here's a simplified version.

```
(while true;do sleep 99999;done)&
```

So I execute the above line from a bash prompt and get something like:
`[1] 12345`

Where `[1]` is the job number and `12345` is the process ID (pid) of the while loop.  I do a `kill 12345` and get:

```
[1]+  Terminated              ( while true; do
    sleep 99999;
done )
```

It looks like the entire script was terminated.  However, I do a `ps aux|grep sleep` and find the sleep command is still going strong but with its own pid!  I can kill the `sleep` and everything seems fine.  However, if I were to kill the sleep first, the while loop starts a new `sleep` pid.  This is such a surprise to me since the sleep is not parallel to the while loop.  The loop itself is a single path of execution.

So I have two questions:

1. Why did the sleep command get its own process ID?
2. How do I easily kill the while loop and the sleep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Sleep gets its own `PID` because it is a process running and just waiting. Try `which sleep` to see where it is.
2. You can use `ps -uf` to see the process tree on your system. From there you can determine what the `PPID` (parent PID) of the shell (the one running the loop) of the sleep is.

Comment: I see.  I was thinking `sleep` was a built-in command in bash, not some process.  It makes more sense now.

Comment: If you're using bash, `type sleep` or `type -a sleep` is preferable to `which`. `which` is an external command; it can't detect aliases, functions, or built-in commands. Compare the  output of `which echo` vs. `type echo`.

Comment: @User1: Things like `echo` are built-in commands because that makes them more efficient (and in some cases, like `cd`, because they have semantics that can't be achieved by running an external command). The efficiency of `sleep` is unimportant, so there's not much point in making it a built-in.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because "sleep" is a process, not a build-in function or similar
2. You could do the following:

   ```
   (while true;do sleep 99999;done)&
   whilepid=$!
   kill -- -$whilepid
   ```

The above code kills the process group, because the PID is specified as a negative number (e.g. -123 instead of 123). In addition, it uses the variable `$!`, which stores the PID of the most recently executed process.

Note:
When you execute any process in background on interactive mode (i.e. using the command line prompt) it creates a new process group, which is what is happening to you. That way, it's relatively easy to "kill 'em all", because you just have to kill the whole process group. However, when the same is done within a script, it doesn't create any new group, because all new processes belong to the script PID, even if they are executed in background (jobs control is disabled by default). To enable jobs control in a script, you just have to put the following at the beginning of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `kill %1`, where `1` is the number you get after launching the command in background?

I did it right now after launching `(while true;do sleep 99999;done)&` and it correctly terminated it.

Answer (score 1):

"ps --ppid" selects all processes with the specified parent pid, eg:

```
$ (while true;do sleep 99999;done)&
[1] 12345

$ ppid=12345 ; kill -9 $ppid $(ps --ppid $ppid -o pid --no-heading)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  kill the process group.

To find the process group of your process run:

```
ps --no-headers -o "%r" -p 15864
```

Then kill the process group using:

```
kill -- -[PGID]
```

You can do it all in one command. Let's try it out:

```
$ (while true;do sleep 99999;done)&
[1] 16151

$ kill -- -$(ps --no-headers -o "%r" -p 16151)
[1]+  Terminated              ( while true; do
    sleep 99999;
done )
```

Answer (score 0):

To kill the `while` loop and the `sleep` using `$!` you can also use a `trap` signal handler inside the subshell.

```
(trap 'kill ${!}; exit' TERM; while true; do sleep 99999 & wait ${!}; done)&
kill -TERM ${!}
```

Comment: Cannot do this after relogin