# Signalling a bash script running in the background in an infinite loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, signals

I have a bash script (sleeping in an infinite loop) running as a background process. I want to periodically signal this process, to do some processing without killing the script, ie. the script on receiving the signal should run a function and then go back to sleep. How do I signal the background process without killing it?

Here's what the code looks like for the script test.sh:

```
MY_PID=$$
echo $MY_PID > test.pid

while true
do
  sleep 5
done
trap 'run' SIGUSR1 

run()
{
 // data processing
}
```

This is how I am running it and triggering it:

```
run.sh &

kill -SIGUSR1 `cat test.pid`
```

Comment: what about using a signal handler?

Comment: First of all, you have to move the trap command above the while loop, or else it will never be executed. And the run function as well for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me.

**EDITED 2014-01-20:** This edit avoids the frequent waking up. Also see this question:
[Bash: a sleep in a while loop gets its own pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452299/bash-a-sleep-in-a-while-loop-gets-its-own-pid)

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_PID=$$
echo $MY_PID > test.pid

trap 'kill ${!}; run' SIGUSR1 

run()
{
    echo "signal!"
}

while true
do
  sleep 1000  & wait ${!}
done
```

Running:

```
> ./test.sh &
[1] 14094
> kill -SIGUSR1 `cat test.pid`
> signal!
>
```

Comment: Is there some way to do this without waking my process up every other second. I don't know if bash provides this option, but does tcl or some other scripting language provide it i wonder. 

Wherein it just sleeps until signal.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. I also added in some code to kill the sleep silently.


trap 'killsub; parse' SIGUSR1

function killsub()
{
    kill -9 ${!} 2>/dev/null
    wait ${!} 2>/dev/null
}